# Where I have to put the Firefox Profile to use it with Splinter

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

I would like to use a specific profile with splinter. But I don't know what I have to put to which location to get this working.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

From this link [here](http://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/drivers/firefox.html#how-to-use-a-specific-profile-for-firefox), you just need to provide your custom profile name as a string like below

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('firefox', profile='my_profile')
```

Comment: Even when I use 'default' I get this error:     
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\splinter\driver\webdriver\firefox.py", lin
e 23, in __init__
    firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile(profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile
.py", line 78, in __init__
    ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", "lock", ".parentlock"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 171, in copytree
    names = os.listdir(src)
WindowsError: [Error 3] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden: 'defa
ult/*.*'

Comment: Translation of the error message tells me that windows was not able to locate the default profile. Are you sure the default profile is present in the appropriate directory splinter is looking for? Did you try creating a new profile and see if that worked?

Comment: I get `WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'default/*.*'`  Where is it searching for a profile and why isn't it finding it? It opens the program correctly so it knows where that is.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/issues/422), passing custom profile name doesn't work. However, passing full path to the profile does.